# Discord Server Bot (js) Heroku Error

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I tried running my Discord bot off Heroku and I keep getting an error that I don't get when simply running the script from command prompt.

> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826804+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object. (/app/app.js:1:79)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826801+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826805+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826806+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826808+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826809+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.826811+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:12.900030+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:28.454851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=vertigo-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=aaa10458-2921-457a-b3c2-57371244cbc8 fwd="HIDDEN" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-04-30T10:06:29.034606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vertigo-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b881c0bc-8011-4487-9aaa-3c6865652044 fwd="HIDDEN dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

[Here is also my Github directory](https://github.com/WastefulNick/vertigo-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have any "dependencies" in your package.json.
Hence, Heroku can't find discord.js that your app depends upon.

To fix that, run:

```
npm install discord.js --save
```

Then commit your package.json, and push to heroku.

Comment: I did this, and it worked, but now I've got new errors.
https://pastebin.com/7aiQxU1E

Comment: Looks like you didn't define BOT_TOKEN anywhere. Is that supposed to be an environment variable? If so, reference it in node.js code as process.env.BOT_TOKEN, and define it on heroku  with heroku config:set BOT_TOKEN=<value>

Comment: Changing it to process.env worked! Thank you and now my bot is up and running!

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, you haven't installed discord.js. Just simply go to your code editor and install discord.js as a saved dependency. Then copy everything inside your package.json to your GitHub.

Hope this helped!